# Hibernate unidirectional @OneToOne using inner join

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am using:

- Spring Boot
- Spring Data JPA
- Spring Data Rest
- Hibernate
- Embedded H2 Database

I am trying to define 2 classes, `First` and `Second`, such that there is a one-to-one mapping from `First` to `Second`. Since I am trying to host queries via Spring Data Rest, which will convert data to JSON, I believe it makes most sense to do EAGER fetches.

So, I have the following:

```
@Entity
public class First {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "FIRST_ID")
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SECOND_ID")
    private Second second;

    // more/getters/settings
}

@Entity
public class Second {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "SECOND_ID")
    private long id;

    // more/getters/settings
}
```

When I search for data of type `First`, I get a SELECT query for the `First` type and then individual SELECT queries for each `Second` where the SECOND_ID matches the foreign key referenced in `First`.

It makes most sense to do an INNER JOIN on this data to do everything in a single query. Such as:

```
SELECT * FROM FIRST
INNER JOIN SECOND ON FIRST.SECOND_ID
```

I can run this query directly on the database and get a table joining the two tables.

How can I get JPA/Hibernate to do this? This seems like an common operation and I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Edit: Note that I am using running the query via automatically generated REST endpoints from Spring Data Rest. I have defined a Spring Data repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "first")
public interface FirstRepository extends CrudRepository<First, Long> {
}
```

Then, by accessing `http://host/first`, I cause Spring to run a findAll operation, which works, but, again, triggers a large number of SELECT queries.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for posting this question. I have trawled for HOURS to figure out how to create the exact use case for my needs with a Spring Data REST JPA oneToOne Unidirectional.

Comment: btw, and for anyone ineterested in the multiple @OneToOne use case where you would add a Third to the above example, _BEWARE_ that if you ALSO then define a CRUD repository for either the Second or Third, it will not work as expected. For some reason, you must not declare a repository for any of the one directionals (Second or subsequent Third or Fourth ad. infitintum.). I do not know why, but it will then fail if you exclude the JSON of say Third as such: `{
  "firstName": "string",
  "second": {
    "secondName": "string"
  }
}` So make sure if you want directional one2ones you omit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the fetch hints on the association are only respected when an Entity is loaded using `EntityManager#find()`.

If you were to get an individual First instance (http://host/first/1) you should see the instance being retrieved with its association in 1 query using LEFT OUTER JOIN (marking the relationship as optional = false) would result in an INNER JOIN) as Spring Data will delegate to the `EntityManager#find()` method.

Spring Data provides a convenience `findAll()` method that simply generates a query `"Select f from First f"`  when you opt to get all instances and which is called when you hit http://host/first. So this obviously doesn't do a JOIN FETCH.

If you were to create a query:

```
@Query("select f from First f join fetch f.second")
public List<First> findAllEager();
```

and hit http://host/first/search/findAllEager then this should load everything in one select.

As that is obviously not very convenient you can then actually just redefine the findAll() method in your repository interface as below:

```
@Query("select f from First f join fetch f.second")
public Iterable<First> findAll();
```

Additional information: when loading an Entity using `EntityManager#find()` then a `@OneToOne` association is always eager in Hibernate unless marked as both non-optional and Lazy.

Comment: Aha! "join fetch" in the HQL was what I was trying to figure out. This does work, but I think the solution from Cepr0 is a better solution for my use case, which avoids the `@Query` entirely.

Comment: Well if you can guarantee EntityGraph will do a join fetch then  I guess so. But you can't always be sure of that....

Comment: Is that not the case? It seems to be doing joins for me, but I can't seem to find any documentation either way.

Comment: It is probably not specified HOW it should be implemented. A provider could do a join or a second select I guess and still meet the specification.

Comment: Actually, I think this is the best approach after all. EntityGraph seems to only allow 1 level of subgraphs.

Answer (score 3):

Try this variant:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "first")
public interface FirstRepository extends CrudRepository<First, Long> {

    @Override
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"second"})
    Iterable<First> findAll();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was looking for. I guess I didn't quite understand what `EntityGraph` did.

Comment: Even better, I guess I can define a `@NamedEntityGraph` and specify `includeAllAttributes = true` and avoid referencing individual attributes.

Comment: It seems one can only specify one level of sub graphs. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39020912/1612093

Comment: What I would REALLY like to know, is if I do _NOT_ add a 2nd (i.e. it is null) using POS on First, how do I prevent it from being show in the findAll(); I could write my own Query I guess...thanks to ALL for this post.